# Bin edges must be unique: array([ 1., 30., 40., 40., 40., 40., 45., 50., 99.]). You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, discretization

while trying to apply the code below I get error massage:

*Bin edges must be unique: array([ 1., 30., 40., 40., 40., 40., 45., 50., 99.]). You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg*

anyone has any idea what could cause to this error massage? and what should I do?

thanks!

```
data['hours.per.week']
```

1        18
3        40
4        40
5        45
6        40
..
32556    40
32557    38
32558    40
32559    40
32560    20
Name: hours.per.week, Length: 30162, dtype: int64

```
pd.qcut(data['hours.per.week'],8).value_counts()
```

Comment: as the error says, pass `duplicates='drop'` to `pd.qcut`.

Comment: thanks! what is the meaning of 'duplicates='drop''?